# Duplicates after aggregating wiith data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm new to data.table, and trying to find how many rows in my table have the same value in two columns.  The resulting table had multiple rows containing the same key combination.  Can someone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

```
labs_raw_df <- data.table(labs_raw)
setkey(labs_raw_df, NAT, LAB_TST_AN_LAB_TST_CD)
lab_pt_count <- labs_raw_df[,
list(n=.N)
  ,by=list(NAT, LAB_TST_AN_LAB_TST_CD)]
```

Both columns are character.

Comment: Shouldn't you be also posting `dput(head(labs_raw, 20))` or something similar that has duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Writing an answer since this is too long for a comment.

I assume that you use data.table 1.8.6.

Let's create some dummy data:

```
set.seed(42)
labs_raw_df <- data.frame(NAT=sample(c("A","B","C"),20,TRUE),
                          LAB_TST_AN_LAB_TST_CD=sample(c("A","B","C"),20,TRUE),
                          value=sample(0:1,20,TRUE))
```

Now your code (with some minor corrections of naming):

```
library(data.table)
labs_raw_dt <- data.table(labs_raw_df)
setkey(labs_raw_dt, NAT, LAB_TST_AN_LAB_TST_CD)
lab_pt_count <- labs_raw_dt[,
                            list(n=.N),
                            by=list(NAT, LAB_TST_AN_LAB_TST_CD)]
print(lab_pt_count)

   NAT LAB_TST_AN_LAB_TST_CD n
1:   A                     A 1
2:   A                     C 3
3:   B                     A 2
4:   B                     B 3
5:   B                     C 2
6:   C                     A 2
7:   C                     B 2
8:   C                     C 5
```

This is the expected result. Can you elaborate on how that doesn't meet your expectation?

Of course we can simplify a bit:

```
lab_pt_count <- labs_raw_dt[,
                            .N,
                            by=key(labs_raw_dt)]
print(lab_pt_count)

   NAT LAB_TST_AN_LAB_TST_CD N
1:   A                     A 1
2:   A                     C 3
3:   B                     A 2
4:   B                     B 3
5:   B                     C 2
6:   C                     A 2
7:   C                     B 2
8:   C                     C 5
```

But the result is the same.

Comment: I was getting multiple rows with the same values of NAT and LAB_TST_AN_LAB_TST_CD.  Hmm.  Well at least I know my code should be working.  Sorry I don't have an reproducible example to share.